# DTED/GeoTiff layer: Get elevation under mouse pointer

Tags: raster, arcobjects, c#, elevation

I have a simple desktop app with a map control. The map data that will be available to show will be either DTED files (Military Analyst's catalog / [MADTEDLayer](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//001t0000025q000000)), or GeoTiffs (created by gdal). I want the user to be able to continuously see the elevation under the position of the mouse cursor. Is it possible to extract this information from the map layer somehow?

PS. I suppose that GeoTiffs have some kind of elevation data embedded since I opened them with GlobalMapper and saw height information under cursor.

Comment: You mean as the mouse moves, the elevation will update without the user clicking the mouse?

Comment: Yes, although this is not the problem. I want to have the elevation data at a given point, no matter if it is right/left click or mouse motion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think you should be able to cast the layer to an IFeatureLayer, fetch each polygon (raster footprint) that intersects the mouse location, then fetch the raster associated with that polygon.

The value of the "Raster" field can be cast as an [IRasterValue2](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#//0025000006v7000000), which can then be passed to [IRasterSurface.PutRaster](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/PutRaster_Method/0009000000wv000000/).  After that you can call [ISurface.InterpolateShape](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/componenthelp/index.html#/InterpolateShape_Method/002500000887000000/).  Caching this will certainly make it faster, though I'm not sure it would be fast enough to be usable with mouse move events.

**Update:**

[image]

Note how the IGG tools uses IRasterSurface, without having 3D analyst.  It is just a regular rastercatalog though - not an MADted, but I don't think that would matter.

```
IFeature feat;
while ((feat = fCur.NextFeature()) != null)
{
    IRasterValue2 rval = feat.get_Value(idx) as IRasterValue2;
    IRasterSurface rSurf = new RasterSurfaceClass();
    sum += ((IRasterProps)rval.Raster).MeanCellSize().X;
    rSurf.PutRaster(rval.Raster, 0);
    m_Surfaces.Add((ISurface)rSurf);
    m_Footprints.Add((IPolygon)feat.ShapeCopy);
}
```

Comment: IRasterSurface is part of 3DAnalyst, for which I don't have license. I have the terrible feeling that I will have to get the actual color value of the specified point in the raster and calculate somehow myself the elevation but I really hope there is an elegant way to do this

Comment: Hmm, that's strange.  It works for me in an arcmap 10.0 extension even though I'm not consuming a 3D analyst license.

Comment: It's not strange, sure it works for *developer* license, but you have to pay FOR EACH *deployment* license, and that is a no-no situation for us (there will be many terminals)

Comment: Oh yeah, I am deploying this to someone who has 3D analyst.  Instead of using IRasterSurface, you should be able to access IRasterValue2.Raster and get the value of the pixel using a pixel block.  It can be done more simply than is shown in [this example](http://help.arcgis.com/en/sdk/10.0/arcobjects_net/conceptualhelp/index.html#/d/000100000022000000.htm).